# R: Delete duplicate rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

A R-dataframe like:

```
x   y
aa   bbd
aa   cce
aa   aa
bb   fff
mm   mm
```

We want to delete rows: aa aa, mm mm, since x=y.
How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can either use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[x!=y]
#   x   y
#1: aa bbd
#2: aa cce
#3: bb fff
```

---

or use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, x!=y)
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned (or from the comments in the dupe link)  `[` would be better than `subset`

```
df1[with(df1, x!=y),]
```

Comment: Or `df1[df1$x != df1$y,]` to avoid the potentially troublesome `subset()`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! So many good solutions.